# How to improve the journal club?

Tags: discussion, journal-club

After three quite nice journal club events, it is high time to add more awesome.

Thus please, add ideas/thoughts/complaints as answers... and vote, as usual.

Comment: we are working on your "guest pass" request for Chat over the next 2 weeks, FYI

Comment: @Jeff Great, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

We can encourage community members to formulate and post appropriate questions on the next paper a week or two beforehand.  This would serve to clarify ideas and perhaps interest more casual users of the site in the JC activity itself.  For example, questions about bagging and random forests could have been (and still would be!) of interest for the last JC (what are they, how do they compare with other methods, are there salient examples of their use in the literature, what software is available, what do you need to know to use them effectively, what advances have been made since Breiman wrote his *Two Cultures* paper, and why do they work?).

Comment: I was thinking more focus on specific topics for the Two Cultures paper would have been helpful. I also think this is a good way to keep the topic open to the community in general without arbitrarily restricting discussion to particular topics.

Answer (score 5):

An all-day affair is too (temporally) diffuse for the limited audience we have been attracting so far.  I would like to suggest reducing it to two definite sessions from three.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a way to notify users of this website when a journal event is going to happen? I would be interested in attending as well but have only found out about them after they have occured.

Comment: There are featured tag (not helping at all) and system message (this blue bar that sometimes appear under the header -- visible, but the SE policy is that each its use is almost considered abuse) -- I was usually using both, but seemingly not enough ;-)

Comment: /cc @mbq And unfortunately, the twitter [statsqa](http://twitter.com/#!/statsqa) account doesn't echo Meta threads... Maybe one solution would be to subscribe to [Mendeley RSS](http://www.mendeley.com/groups/999241/crossvalidated-journal-club/) feeds for CVJC: with updates of new articles, you will be notified of the upcoming JC? (This assumes that articles proposed for CVJC are mirrored on Mendeley as soon as they are notified here.)

Comment: I just saw the headline at the top of CV, very exciting!